# Lifetime of Python class attribute

Tags: python, lifetime, class-attributes

What's the lifetime of a class attribute, in Python?  If no instances of the class are currently live, might the class *and its class attributes* be garbage-collected, and then created anew when the class is next used?

For example, consider something like:

```
class C(object):
    l = []

    def append(self, x):
        l.append(x)
```

Suppose I create an instance of `C`, append 5 to `C.l`, and then that instance of `C` is no longer referenced and can be garbage-collected.  Later, I create another instance of `C` and read the value of `C.l`.  Am I guaranteed `C.l` will hold `[5]`?  Or is it possible that the class itself and its class attributes might get garbage-collected, and then `C.l = []` executed a second time later?

Or, to put it another way: Is the lifetime of a class attribute "forever"?  Does a class attribute have the same lifetime as a global variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked several questions.

> What's the lifetime of a class attribute, in Python?

A class attribute lives as long as there is a reference to it. Since the class holds a reference, it will live as at least long as the class lives, assuming that the class continues to hold the reference. Additionally, since each object holds a reference, it will live at least as long as all of the objects, assuming that each object continues to hold the reference.

> Am I guaranteed `C.l` will hold `[5]`?

In the hypothetical that you describe, yes.

> Or is it possible that the class itself and its class attributes might get garbage-collected, and then `C.l = []` executed a second time later?

Not given your hypothetical that you are able to construct an instance of `C`. If you are able to construct a second instance of `C`, then `C` must exist, and so too must `C.l`

> Is the lifetime of a class attribute "forever"?

No. The lifetime of a class attribute follows the lifetime rules of any object. It exists as long a reference to it exists. In the case of `C.l`, a reference exists in the class, and a reference exists in each instance. If you destroy all of those, then `C.l` will also be destroyed.

> Does a class attribute have the same lifetime as a global variable?

Sort of: a class attribute exists until the last reference goes away. A global variable also exists until the last reference goes away. Neither of these are guaranteed to last the entire duration of the program.

Also, a class defined at module scope **is** a global variable. So the class (and, by implication, the attribute) have the same lifetime as a global variable in that case.

Answer (score 2):

> If no instances of the class are currently live, might the class and its class attributes be garbage-collected, and then created anew when the class is next used?

No. There is no "next use" of a class that's been garbage-collected, because the only way it can be garbage-collected is if there's no way left to use it.

> Suppose I create an instance of `C`, append 5 to `C.l`, and then that instance of `C` is no longer referenced and can be garbage-collected. Later, I create another instance of `C` and read the value of `C.l`. Am I guaranteed `C.l` will hold `[5]`?

Yes. The class has a live reference because you created another instance, and the list has a live reference as an attribute on the class.

> Does a class attribute have the same lifetime as a global variable?

If the class holds a reference to something, that something will live at least as long as the class.